# Subset enumeration by size is not primitive recursive?

Tags: computability, recursion

For integers $N\geq n \geq 1$, let

$$
S_{N,n}=\Bigg\lbrace (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N)\in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace ^N \ \Bigg|
\sum_{k=1}^{N} x_k=n
 \ \Bigg\rbrace
$$
  Note that $S_{N,n}$ is naturally in bijection with the $n$-subsets
of $[1..N]$, so that $S_{N,n}$ has cardinality $\binom{N}{n}$.

Let $f:{\mathbb N}^4 \to {\mathbb N}$. I say that $f$ is a subset-enumerating
function iff for all $N\geq n\geq 1$,

$$
\Bigg\lbrace (f(N,n,k,1),f(N,n,k,2),\ldots,f(N,n,k,N)) \ \Bigg|
1 \leq k \leq \binom{N}{n}
 \ \Bigg\rbrace=S_{N,n}
$$
  Question : can $f$ be subset-enumerating and primitive recursive at the same time ?

My thoughts :  I think that the answer is NO because heuristically this kind of enumeration is related to Goedel numbering and demands a complexity higher than just primitive recursive.

Closely related : [Closed-Form Solution for Permutation Table](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218514/closed-form-solution-for-permutation-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand that any function with time complexity in the Exponential Hierarchy is recursive primitive...
I think that you can find a program that compute $f$ in polynomial time, but even with exponential time (or double exponential time $O(2^{2^n})$), it's enough to prove it is recursive primitive.

As your definition is very simple, $f(N,n,k,i)$ can enumerate all elements of $\{0,1\}^N$ and stop to the $k^{th}$ element that is in $S_{N,n}$ and return its $i^{th}$ component. This is not a very optimized program, but it's enough to proof that $f$ is recursive primitive. In fact, it's very hard to define **non primitive** function (almost impossible without double recursion like for Ackermann function or without using universal machine like the halting problem).

Comment: forgive me for not being convinced, as my recursivity theory is a little bit rusty. What I know is that the function is  primitive recursive if we can find a program that does not use the $\mu$-operator. It is not clear at all to me that the program you suggest will not need the $\mu$-operator.

Comment: You only need bounded (by $2^N$) for loops...@EwanDelanoy But the argument on time complexity is stronger and sufficient.

Comment: Ah yes, I had forgotten about that one. Thank you